# Is there any method of installing Xposed framework on non-rooted devices with stock recovery?

Tags: stock-android, 4.3-jelly-bean, xposed-framework

I am trying to figure out if there is  a method of installing Xposed framework on **stock ROM** without custom recovery (e.g CWM or TWRP). The conventional method that I am well familiar with is installing the framework via Xposed app on a rooted device.

I researched a bit and most workarounds were promising although not successful:

According to [this source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/installing-xposed-framwork-root-t3440852), the method involves setting the system partition writable then pushing the necessary files via `adb` commands however fails with `Permission denied` errors. I suspect bootloader issues (which seems to be locked) here but not very sure.

The other way, [described here](http://www.xiaomitoday.com/heres-how-to-install-xposed-framework-without-custom-recovery/) doesn't need custom recovery. This involves installing a third party application (FlashFire) to flashed unsigned `.zip` but unfortunately seems to require root (from description).

The last one involves using new [systemless xposed framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-systemless-xposed-t3388268) but the problem is that it supports android 5+ versions.

So is there any convenient way of installing xposed framework on **stock recovery without root**?

**Edit**

Following important discussions raised in comments, I guess I have to explain why I want to bypass root-based installation procedure, it's because the device in use is not rooted, so I need to use a non root installation mrthod.

Contrary to the comments however, some users have used [Xposed without **root**:](http://www.tested.com/tech/android/460074-how-use-xposed-framework-android-extreme-customization/)

> **Xposed only needs root access when you install** it, then everything
>   else is completely transparent to the user because the framework acts
>   as a **separate conduit** to the system -- it doesn't go through the usual
>   SU channels

Also the device is running Android 4.3 stock

Comment: What is point when Xposed requirers root to work?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје are you sure it requires root to work?? Other sources confirmed otherwise?

Comment: Even systemless Xposed (A Magisk module) requires root to work, you must be rooted for Xposed to be installed and function. Also, you are referring to JellyBean, is that tag correct? I don't think "systemless" root or other "systemless" mods can be achieved without Marshmallow or higher.

Comment: Straight up, no. You have no entry point to either system or systemless approaches. The first XDA link you referred to worked for OP only because he had a rooted shell, which can exist on non-production builds without the device itself being truely rooted.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't interested in going back to answer my post, however its pretty funny how things that were deemed impossible 5 years ago are becoming possible as technology age, anyway there seems to be possibilities of achieving what I wanted 5 years ago.

There exists a plethora of Xposed solutions that can be utilized sans any hindrance. Depending on the given use cases, it is feasible to inject a particular application in order for it to load the xposed module and perform as desired (which aligns with my objectives).

1. [LSPatch](https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPatch)

> Rootless implementation of LSPosed framework, integrating Xposed API
> by inserting dex and so into the target APK. Supported Versions
>
> ```
> Min: Android 9
> Max: In theory, same with LSPosed
> ```

2. [SPatch](http://spatch.die.lu/)
3. [VirtualXposed](https://virtualxposed.com/)

et. cetera. The main point here is that it is quite possible to used rootless xposed method as long as the module doesn't need access to the system. Some modules are just specific to the applications that use them.